# Unit testing canActivate as an Observable crashes karma

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs

When I try to unit test my guard, it fails in an odd way.  If I try to subscribe to the Observable returned by `canActivate`, the tests freeze and eventually Karma disconnects citing a timeout:

> WARN [HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.13.0)]: Disconnected (1
>   times), because no message in 10000 ms.

The guard itself functions fine in the application, it's only causing issues in the test.  Raising the timeout value does not solve the issue.

This **doesn't** crash:

```
it('...', async(() => {
    guard.canActivate(
        { params: { id: 'a' } as any } as ActivatedRouteSnapshot
    );
}));
```

This **does** crash (only change is adding `.subscribe()`):

```
it('...', async(() => {
    guard.canActivate(
        { params: { id: 'a' } as any } as ActivatedRouteSnapshot
    ).subscribe();
}));
```

This **does** crash too, using Jasmine's done callback:

```
it('...', done => {
    guard.canActivate(
        { params: { id: 'a' } as any } as ActivatedRouteSnapshot
    ).subscribe(x => done());
});
```

---

Test source:

```
describe('Guard', () => {
    let store: Store<fromRoot.State>;
    let guard: Guard;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
                StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)
            ],
            providers: [
                Guard
            ]
        });

        store = TestBed.get(Store);
        guard = TestBed.get(Guard);
    });

    it('...', async(() => {
        guard.canActivate(
            { params: { id: 'a' } as any } as ActivatedRouteSnapshot
        ).subscribe();

        expect(1).toBe(1);
    }));
});
```

Guard source:

```
@Injectable()
export class Guard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
        private router: Router
    ) {}

    getFromStoreOrApi(id: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.store.select(fromRoot.selectState)
            .do(state => {
                if (!state.entities[id]) {
                    this.store.dispatch(new actions.Get(id));
                }
            });
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.getFromStoreOrApi(route.params.id)
            .switchMap(() => Observable.of(true))
            .catch(() => Observable.of(false));
    }
}
```

Comment: you should be faking the `getFromStoreOrApi()` method as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Karma is crashing. It's waiting for the Observable to complete.

```
it('...', async(() => {
    guard.canActivate(
         { params: { id: 'a' } as any } as ActivatedRouteSnapshot
    ).take(1).subscribe();
}));
```

Add a `take(1)` or a `first()` operator to auto complete after the first emitted value.